# Did Darth Vader intend to start the rebel Alliance?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-vader

I read on Star Wars wiki about [the birth of the rebellion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Alliance_to_Restore_the_Republic) which mentions Darth Vader´s secret apprentice Galen Marek who then forms the alliance:

> Darth Vader orders his secret apprentice to forge a rebellion against the Empire.

Was it actually Darth Vader's intent to start a rebellion against an empire which he later on would command, and if so why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think it was a long con by both the Emperor and Vader that blew up in their faces. They knew they had opposition so they decided to get those elements together and wipe them out, using Starkiller unwittingly as the instigator.

So:

Originally it seems like Vader and Starkiller are going to usurp the Emperor

EXCEPT Vader betrays Starkiller to the Emperor and kills him

EXCEPT Vader had only made it seem Starkiller was dead, so that he could now secretly go work on a new plan of gathering the seperate enemies of the Empire into one united fighting force (and I think this is where it is suggested Vader will take over as new boss of everyone)

EXCEPT Vader betrays Starkiller AGAIN and takes the Rebel leaders to the Death Star

EXCEPT Starkiller arrives on the Death Star, rescues the Rebel leaders, fights the Emperor, dies a martyr, encouraging the Rebel leaders to stay united and keep on fighting.

This all occurs in *[Star Wars: The Force Unleashed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars%3a_The_Force_Unleashed)*. It's a really good game and you should go play it.

Comment: This isn't pertinent to your question but just more about the game. It's set in the gap between the trilogies and ties together elements of each. There's conservation of planets and characters which I found refreshing, whilst giving the Jedi basically superhero abilities. It has TWO endings and whilst one is canonical there are several missions set in the other universe but now in the timeframe of the original trilogy, giving a dark take on our favourite movies.

Comment: The OP doesn't mention gaming at all and you give no title. I'll go ahead and assume it's **not** Pac-Man you're talking about.  ;)

Comment: @Meat Trademark: That game would be [Star Wars: The Force Unleashed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Unleashed). Amazing plot for an action title!

Comment: @WillF See? I just *knew* it wasn't Pac-Man. Thanks.

Comment: Keep in mind, there is a second Force Unleashed now, don't play that one, it's just... ugh...

Comment: Is this still cannon after the events of Rogue One?